# Java multithreading: how to wait for a method to return a valid value

Tags: java, multithreading

I am faced with the following situation in my Java app that use Threads.

I need to **stop my thread and wait** until `otherObject.methodFoo()` returns a **NOT NULL** value.

Something like this... (obviously this version does not work)

```
synchronized(otherObject.methodFoo())
{ 
    while (otherObject.methodFoo()==null)
    {
        otherObject.methodFoo().wait();
    }
    otherObject.methodFoo().nowCanDoStuff();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To make things more complicate: `otherObject.methodFoo()` will return NOT NULL only when A DIFFERENT THREAD finishes his work

..so I will not be able to give to the 2 threads CountDownLatches or Semaphores...

Comment: How do you trigger two threads? Are those runnables?

Comment: yes, 2 different Runnables submitted at different times to an executor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not doing anything?

```
synchronized methodFoo()
{ 
    while (methodFoo()==null);
    methodFoo().nowCanDoStuff();
}
```

This loops forever until methodFoo() returns something other than null. Of course also your specific code loops forever due to recursion so do not call methodFoo() inside methodFoo(), so do something like:

```
synchronized otherMethodFoo()
{ 
    while (methodFoo()==null);
    methodFoo().nowCanDoStuff();
}
```

Also:

```
methodFoo().wait();
```

Is unclear. wait() is a method of a method? Or a method in the main object? or...

Comment: it's `otherObject.methodFoo()` I think your suggestion is the closest to a right answer the point is that if I do , the point is that if I do synchronized (otherObject.methodFoo())
{ 
    while (otherobject.methodFoo()==null);
    otherobject.methodFoo().nowCanDoStuff();
} I get a NPE :-)))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)'s method `acquire`
[Here a tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-semaphores.html)
Basically, `semaphore.acquire();` blocks the program's flow until a permit is released with `semaphore.release();`
You can also specify the initial number of permits (in the constructor) and how many permits release in `semaphore.release(3);`.
You can imagine the permits as contained in a buffer and every time the `acquire` method is called, a permit is removed from the buffer. When there aren't any permits remained in it, the `acquire` call will be blocking, until another permit is released.

Comment: Hi Tommy, I don't see the connection... :-(

Comment: In your thread you can `acquire` a permit, which will block the thread flow, then in the method that will return the value you can `release` a permit, so then your thread will continue to execute

Comment: as written in the documentation; `Semaphores are often used to restrict the number of threads than can access some (physical or logical) resource.`

Answer (score 1):

Give [`COuntDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) a look. Especially the `await()` method.

**update as  per added info**

```
public class OtherClass implements Runnable {
   CountDownLatch latch;
   test(Countdownlatch latch) { 
      this.latch = latch;
   }
   public void run(){
    latch.await(); //Block until latch is decreased in other thread.
    // does something.
   } 
}

public class SomeOtherClass implements Runnable {
   CountDownLatch latch;
   test(Countdownlatch latch) { 
      this.latch = latch;
   }
   public void run(){
    // does some other thing.
    latch.countDown(); //decrease the latch count.
   } 
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    OtherClass other = new OtherClass(latch);
    SomeOtherClass other = new SomeOtherClass(latch);
    //create threads and then start. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly that you just want to stop the current thread until some method returns not null value then you can do something like this -

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicBoolean gotNotNullValue = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        FirstThread ft = new FirstThread();
        ft.setGotNotNullValue(gotNotNullValue);
        ft.setDone(done);

        SecondThread st = new SecondThread();
        st.setGotNotNullValue(gotNotNullValue);
        st.setDone(done);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(ft);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(st);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class FirstThread implements Runnable {
    private int testCounter = 0;
    private AtomicBoolean gotNotNullValue;
    private AtomicBoolean done;

    public void setGotNotNullValue(AtomicBoolean gotNotNullValue) {
        this.gotNotNullValue = gotNotNullValue;
    }

    public void setDone(AtomicBoolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!done.get()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
            gotNotNullValue.set(methodFoo() != null);
            System.out.println("gotNotNullValue: " + gotNotNullValue + ", testCounter: " + testCounter);
        }
    }

    private Object methodFoo() {
        System.out.println("Inside methodFoo()");
        if (testCounter++ < 100) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Object();
    }
}

class SecondThread implements Runnable {
    private AtomicBoolean gotNotNullValue;
    private AtomicBoolean done;

    public void setGotNotNullValue(AtomicBoolean gotNotNullValue) {
        this.gotNotNullValue = gotNotNullValue;
    }

    public void setDone(AtomicBoolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!gotNotNullValue.get()) {
            System.out.println("Got null value, waiting");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        done.set(true);
        System.out.println("Got not null value, proceeding further");
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the 2 threads are not members of the same class (hence cannot share variables) and there can be LOTS of threads

Comment: Ok, updated my test program which now has different thread classes but shares objects to communicate with each other.

Comment: Also the other approach could be to share a SynchronousQueue across all threads.  Threads poll the queue and remain blocked until some other thread adds a not null value to the same queue. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html for more details.